# SQL join table lower date and lower id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got the following two tables
START AND REPEAT

START

```
INSPECID=======SCORE    
1--------------3    
2--------------1    
3--------------4
```

REPEAT

```
ID========INSPECID========SCORE========DATE
1---------1---------------9------------12/01/2016    
2---------1---------------1------------11/01/2016    
3---------2---------------2------------29/01/2016
4---------2---------------4------------01/01/2016
5---------2---------------3------------22/01/2016
6---------2---------------5------------02/01/2016
7---------2---------------1------------11/01/2016    
8---------2---------------1------------01/01/2016    
9---------3---------------1------------02/01/2016   
10--------3---------------2------------09/01/2016
```

I am expecting as below

```
INCREASED------1
DECREASED------2
EQUAL----------0
```

Rules

1) Join tables by INSPECID

2) When more than 1 INSPECID is found in REPEAT table consider the score from the lower date.

3) when both INSPECID is matched and date is matched than consider the lower ID in the REPEAT table, so ID 4 and ID 8 has same date and same INPECTID but consider the ID 4 score which is 4.

Comment: By "lower date", do you mean the oldest date? Also, what SQL have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self join with `REPEAT` table to pick the oldest row

```
select s.*,a.*
from `START` s
join `REPEAT` a on s.INSPECID = a.INSPECID
left join `REPEAT` b on a.INSPECID = b.INSPECID
and case when a.DATE = b.DATE
         then a.ID > b.ID
         else a.DATE > b.DATE
     end
where b.INSPECID is null
```

> For conflict when INSPECID and DATE is same use CASE to choose row with lowest ID

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b888f/3)

Updated for desired result set

```
select t.result,count(t1.result) cnt
from (
      select 'Increased' result
      union
      select 'Decreased' result
      union
      select 'Equal' result
) t
left join (
select s.score,a.id,a.DATE,
case when s.SCORE > a.SCORE
     then 'Increased'
     when s.SCORE < a.SCORE
     then 'Decreased'
     else 'Equal'
end result
from `START` s
join `REPEAT` a on s.INSPECID = a.INSPECID
left join `REPEAT` b on a.INSPECID = b.INSPECID
and case when a.DATE = b.DATE
         then a.ID > b.ID
         else a.DATE > b.DATE
     end
where b.INSPECID is null 
) t1 using(result)
group by t.result
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b888f/15)

Comment: Hi Khalid, thanks for reply can this be shown as a count of increased, decrease and equal as per my question.

Comment: @GROVER_SYAAN I don't get this part ? Can you elaborate it more how you are calculating these rows as increased , decreased and equal

Comment: going through all rows of table 1 , INSPECTID 1 row has a decreased count where out of two rows from repeat table you consider the lowest date(11/01/2016) score which is  1 and its a decresed when compared to score 3

Comment: so you go through all rows in table 1 and add to increased, decreased and equal counts

Comment: your fiddel is almost right, so in first row the score has decreased in second score has increased and third row score has decreased again, so i should get increased 1 and decreased 2 and equal 0

Comment: @GROVER_SYAAN i have updated my post i hope this is what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  The following uses the `group_concat()` trick for calculating the first and last scores.  It then puts these into the categories that you want:

```
select w.which, count(r.INSPECID)     
from (select 'DECREASING' as which union all
      select 'INCREASING' as which union all
      select 'EQUAL' as which
     ) w left join
     (select r.INSPECID,
             (substring_index(group_concat(score order by date), ',', 1) + 0) as first_score,
             (substring_index(group_concat(score order by date desc), ',', 1) + 1) as last_score
      from repeat r
      group by INSPECID
     ) r
     ON (last_score > first_score and w.which = 'INCREASING') or
        (last_score < first_score and w.which = 'DECREASING') or
        (last_score = first_score and w.which = 'INCREASING')
group by w.which;
```

Note that the first table is not necessary.

Comment: I think the OP intends for the first score to be that from the START table, and compared to the "oldest" date for a particular INSPECID, and not the oldest and youngest dated matching rows. Interesting and unique approach though!

Comment: @SloanThrasher . . . The OP does not show a date in the `START` table.

Comment: @GordonLindoff: Correct, but the OP says to use that as the starting rating, and the lowest date from the other table for the comparison.